# Displaying custom error page on test case http://localhost/test. and htttp://localhost/test:

Tags: asp.net, web-config, custom-error-pages

I need to redirect on error to error page on below test scenario,
http://localhost/admin800/test.
http://localhost/admin800/test:

Here is my code,

```
<system.web>
    <compilation debug="true" targetFramework="4.0" />
    <httpRuntime targetFramework="4.0"  />
    <customErrors  mode="On" defaultRedirect="Error1">
      <error statusCode="404" redirect="/admin600/error.aspx"/>
    </customErrors>

  </system.web>
    <system.webServer>     
        <directoryBrowse enabled="false" />
      <httpErrors errorMode="Custom"  defaultResponseMode="ExecuteURL" existingResponse="Replace">
        <remove statusCode="500" subStatusCode="-1" />
        <remove statusCode="404" subStatusCode="-1" />
        <remove statusCode="403" subStatusCode="-1" />
        <error statusCode="404" path="/admin600/error.aspx" responseMode="ExecuteURL" />
        <error statusCode="500" prefixLanguageFilePath="" path="/admin600/error.aspx" responseMode="ExecuteURL" />
        <error statusCode="403"  path="/admin600/error.aspx" responseMode="ExecuteURL" />
      </httpErrors>
    </system.webServer>
```

Let me know what additional code i need to add in this web.configI have done project in web application project not in MVC.Looking forward to hear from you at the earliest.

Thanks in advance.
George

Answer (score 0):

I am Using This Code In My Application:

`<customErrors defaultRedirect="error.aspx" mode="On" />`
Or This :

```
<customErrors mode="RemoteOnly" defaultRedirect="GenericErrorPage.htm">
            <error statusCode="403" redirect="NoAccess.htm" />
            <error statusCode="404" redirect="FileNotFound.htm" />
        </customErrors>
```